# What does a '?' following a type mean with generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following enigmatic declaration in C#:

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime?> badCameras = new Dictionary<string, DateTime?>();
```

This was written by a programmer no longer here & IS compiling! What ever does the '?' mean following DateTime object? Has it something to do with a struct? I've searched online & am finding nothing? BTW, this is .NET3.5.

Thanks

Comment: [Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime?` is compiler sugar for `Nullable<DateTime>`. Effectively, nullable types allow for the use of `null` when dealing with [*value* types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) that don't normally support `null`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The ? in that context is a shortcut for `Nullable<T>`. In your example, its equivalant to:

```
Dictionary<string, Nullable<DateTime>>
```

The main purpose is to allow value types to hold the `null` value.